# Where should I put my ShowCaseView builder in this case?

Tags: java, android, showcaseview

I have this in my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupHomeScreen();
    }
    public void setupHomeScreen() {
        File latestPic = getMostRecentSnappiePicture();
        if(latestPic != null){
            //display pic
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                layout.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(latestPic.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
            else{
                layout.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(latestPic.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
            //hide tutorial
            findViewById(R.id.howitworks).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        else{
            //show tutorial
            findViewById(R.id.howitworks).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
                .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
                .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
                .hideOnTouchOutside()
                .build();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in onCreate, it calls setupHomeScreen and checks if a file exists. If it doesn't exist, it displays a tutorial "howitworks" layout image as well as building a showcase view.

So this all works fine and well. The only issue comes when trying to leave the activity while the showcaseView is still there, OR sometimes even after you exit the showcase view and try and launch the new activity, this error comes up: [ShowcaseView - width and height must be > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456289/showcaseview-width-and-height-must-be-0)

As you can see in the answers, the solution is to only create the showcase view in the callback after the original view has been created like so:

```
someView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // my ShowcaseView builder here
    }
});
```

The only thing is, I have no idea where to put this, since my showcase view should only show up if the file from getMostRecentSnappiePicture() is null. So how can I put the view creation callback inside of my logic to check that that file is null first?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're highlighting the HOME button instead of the 'howitworks' view. Try switching the line

```
 .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
```

with

```
 .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.howitworks,this));
```

Also, the following video might help. It's 20 minute tutorial on how to use ShowCaseView inside an activity with 3 buttons. He is declaring an onClickListener where he changes programmatically the TargetView highlighted by the showCaseView

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zdeFSBplps

The video is in spanish, but at least you'll be able to follow the steps, since he's writing the code from scratch.

Comment: Working answer. The video was also very helpful. Thank you.